# How to remove an Item from scope AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

```
**This  is my drink list, with a delete button for each ingredient.**

![My Ingredient Page][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPNHs.png

**1. Relevant template html:**

div.row.editRow(ng-repeat="drink in drinks | orderBy: 'name'")
  form(ng-submit="editDrink(drink)")
    div.col-md-3 
      input(value="{{drink.name}}", ng-model="drink.name")
    div.col-md-3
      input(value="{{drink.image}}", ng-model="drink.image")
    div.col-md-1.text-right 
      a(ng-click="addNewIngredient()") +
    div.col-md-4
      div.row(ng-repeat="ingredient in drink.ingredients")
        div.col-md-7
          select.mixers(value="{{ingredient.name}}", ng-model="ingredient.name", ng-options="i for i in ingredientsList")
        div.col-md-4
          input.addForm.ingredient(value="{{ingredient.amount}}", ng-model="ingredient.amount", style="width: 100px;")
        div.col-md-1 
          a(ng-click="removeIngredientEdit($index)") -
    div.col-md-1
      button.btn Save
```

**2. Relevant controller method:**

```
 $scope.removeIngredientEdit = function (index) { 
    $scope.newDrink.ingredients.splice(index);
     console.log('Removed ingredient at index ' );
  };
```

When I do this nothing happens. I am using mongodb to store my drink information. I am new to Angular JS and do not know what to do.

Comment: .splice(index, 1) The second parameter specifies how many array elements to remove.

Comment: So I should put one because I want to delete only one ? And then it would work ?

Comment: When I made those changes nothing happens and the console says 
"Removed ingredient at  0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, instead of

```
ng-click="removeIngredientEdit(drink)"
```

try something like:

```
ng-click="removeIngredientEdit($parent.$index, $index)"
```

The first parameter, `$parent.$index` is the index of the drink. `$index` is the index of the ingredient. Then you can do something like this in your controller:

```
$scope.removeIngredient = function (i, j) {
    $scope.drinks[i].ingredients.splice(j, 1)
}
```

Comment: I changed it to that, and I still have nothing I tried that at first as well because a lot of tutorials use that.Thanks

Comment: Have any suggestions?

Comment: I have done what you said and then in the js my function  $scope.removeIngredientEdit = function ($index) { 
    $scope.drinks[$index].ingredients.splice($index,1);
    console.log($index);
    }; But I doesn't always delete the correct one.

Comment: Ahh, probably have to pass through the index of the drink as well. Something like removeIngredient($parent.$index, $index)

Comment: $parent.$index is the index of the drink, $index is the index of the ingredient.